# Can anyone explain the output for scanned value of the following program..?

Tags: c, printf, output, scanf

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    printf("%d\n", scanf("%d", &i) );
    return 0;
}
```

If some value is supplied to `scanf()` the output of the program is still 1. Why ?

Answer (score 2):

> if some value is supplied scanf but the output of the program is still 1. Why?

Because `scanf` returns an `int` as [per the documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf). `scanf` will return the total number of items scanned and assigned successfully.

In your case, `scanf` will return 1 if it was successful in scanning an `int` from the `stdin`, else it will return 0. It will also return `-1` on encountering `EOF`. Then, this value is printed by the `printf` you have.

---

If you want to print the value of `i`, seperate the `scanf` and the `printf`, i.e, use

```
int i;
scanf("%d", &i)
printf("%d\n", i);
```

instead of

```
int i;
printf("%d\n" , scanf("%d", &i) );
```

Answer (score 2):

In the below statement,

```
printf("%d\n" , scanf("%d", &i) );
```

you're **not** printing the value *scanned and stored* by `scanf()`, you're printing the *return value* of `scanf()`.

The value, scanned by `scanf()` will be stored in the supplied argument, here, the variable `i`.

Remember, [`scanf()` **does not return** the *scanned value*, it **returns** the number of items it successfully matched and assigned](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf).

If you want to print the scanned value, you have to use the same variable where the value is stored, i.e., `i`.

```
  printf("The scanned value is %d\n", i);
```

---

That said, as a note, the recommended signature for `main()` is `int main(void)`.

Answer (score 1):

The return type of `scanf()` is number of items of the argument list successfully filled.In your case one item is being read so if successful `1` will be returned by `scanf()` Similarly the following would return `2` because there are two items being read.

```
 int i,j;
 printf("%d\n" , scanf("%d %d", &i,&j) );
```